# JPA: Join particular column from another table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to join only one column from another table.

I have 2 entities now:

```
@Entity
public class Message {

    ....

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ATTRIBUTE_ID")
    private Attribute attribute;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ATTRIBUTE_TABLE")
public class Attribute {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
}
```

And I want to simplify code and don't use entity for only one column:

```
@Entity
@SecondaryTable(name = "ATTRIBUTE_TABLE", pkJoinColumns = 
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ATTRIBUTE_ID")),
public class Message {

    ....

    @Column(table = "ATTRIBUTE_TABLE", name = "NAME")
    private String attribute;
}
```

But @SecondaryTable JoinColumn cannot reference a non-primary key.
How to add a column from another table without using additional entity for it?

Comment: Did you get answer for this? I am also looking for same scenario.